# Svelte app bug: uncompleted todos are not returned

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am working on a small todo app with Svelte. I list 10 todos from jsonplaceholder.

I want to count the todos whose `completed` property is equal to `false`:

```
const apiURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
const limit = 10;
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.svelte';
let todos = [];
let unsolvedTodos = [];

onMount(() => {
    getTodos();
});

const getTodos = () => {
    fetch(`${apiURL}?&_limit=${limit}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => todos = data);
}

const getUnsolvedTodos = () => {
    unsolvedTodos = todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.completed === false;
    })
}

$:console.log(unsolvedTodos);
```

As can be seen in **[this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7bf36356582b4e7da33d3e7bd137dacc?version=3.38.2)**, the `unsolvedTodos` array is empty.

---

#### EDIT

I got the *list of unsolved todos* and its *length*, but I can not use it in the header component.

```
const getTodos = () => {
    fetch(`${apiURL}?&_limit=${limit}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => todos = data)
    .then(getUnsolvedTodos);
}

const getUnsolvedTodos = () => {
    unsolvedTodos = todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.completed === false;
    })
}

$:console.log(unsolvedTodos.length);
```

As visible in the REPL, using `<span class="count">{unsolvedTodos.length}</span>` throws an `unsolvedTodos is not defined` error, evan though I imported the ToDoList.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you calling your function `getUnsolvedTodosTodos` anywhere?

Comment: @devnull69 I n the line `$:console.log(unsolvedTodos)`.

Comment: No this is only logging the content of unsolvedTodos, but it is not calling the function at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply importing a component into another will not expose its properties. So you cannot do `import TodoList from './TodoList.svelte';` and expect *unsolvedTodos* to be available in the Header. All you have available is the **component** TodoList.  From your code, you seem to make the same mistake in *TodoItem* where you try to access the undefined variable `todos`.

The problem you are facing here is that you need to share data between two or more components that have no direct relation to each other (they are not parent and child).  Sharing data between such components is usually solved in one of two ways:

**Through the parent**

The first solution is to move the state or data to the parent. In your case that would mean that the actual list of todos and all logic regarding adding, removing, toggling, etc... is stored in `App.svelte` and the other components become mere *representation components* to which you pass this list.

```html
<script>
  import TodoList from './TodoList.svelte';

  let todos = []
  // Here comes logic for fetching the list and changing the state
</script>

<TodoList todos={todos} />
```

As you see here, the App is responsible for keeping track of the todos, while the List component would only show them.  If you want to add a new item to the list, you would do it *here* and not in *TodoList* Same if you change the state of an item, you have to bubble it all the way up to *App.svelte* and not change the state in *TodoItem* that one would be purely showing the current state.

This last part is a bit cumbersome so a better option might be to

**use a store**

Using [stores][1] you can define one single point to keep your state and then import that state into the components that need it, for example the TodoList would be:

```html
<script>
  import { todos } from './store.js';
  import TodoItem from './TodoItem.svelte';
</script>

{#each $todos as todo}
  <TodoItem todo={todo} />
{/each}
```

Similarly *TodoItem* could import this store and update the responding element in the list. (Best would be to use a custom store for this so all logic really now resides in the store object).

Comment: How would you (re)do this small project? What would be the best aproach?

Comment: use the store approach

Comment: Why do I have to _toggle_ a todo item from the `App. svelte` component? Shouldn't every component have its own logic in itself?

Comment: It's a matter of organization, it's common to differentiate between representation and business logic, you can of course put it in the component itself, but you still have to somehow propagate the change to the source data such that the overall state of the entire application is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use function to calculate but use filter code inline and prefix with $ to make it reactive

$: unsolvedTodos = todos.filter(todo => {
return todo.completed === false;
});

And use this value in template